# Binary Number (of length > Integer.MaxValue) modulo another Binary Number

Tags: algorithm, scala, binary, biginteger

Say I have two integers, both too large to represent using `BigInt`

For my intended use case, let's say the binary representation of these numbers is more than `Integer.MaxValue` bits long. I would like to compute the remainder using modular arithmetic, for the purposes of checking if a number is a multiple of another number.

Is there any reasonably efficient algorithm that would allow me to compute such a result? (These are massive numbers, with significant memory footprint considerations, so I'm not expecting "fast")

If it is important to note, the number (`a`) will be mod another number (`b`) such that `a > b`, i.e. `a % b`, ultimately to check if `a % b == 0`

I'm not looking for a specific implementation, but the only thing I was able to find in my search was for checking the result of a BitString mod an `Int` (See: [Modulo of a large Binary String](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-of-a-large-binary-string/)), so any ideas or perhaps even a more specific term for this operation would be of huge help to me. An existing algorithm in any language as a reference would be ideal, and I would be very grateful to be directed at any such resources.

EDIT: Some other caveats:

- I do not know the difference between the numbers (though it could be computed)
- I could repeatedly add the smaller number (`b`) to an accumulator until the result is at least the same bitlength as `a`, and compare each bit, but if the difference is large, this seems rather not elegant.
- I could compute the difference, calculate the multiple to augment `b` by and then check for equality (this seems like a reasonable solution, but I do hope that perhaps there are tricks or existing solutions that are a little smarter than that, I'm really not sure).

Comment: I've never dug into this topic, but I recommend reaching out to CS papers, googling terms like "efficient representation of big numbers".

Comment: @michaJlS Thank you for your suggestion of search terms. To be quite honest, your terms yielded nothing of note to address this issue, as numeric representations are not what I am looking for due to size considerations. It is infeasible (impractical, and not supported using existing numeric structures) to have a "number" that is billions of digits long, most implementations opt for bit-strings or just strings, however, when doing modulus, the operator, as I have seen so far, is always with an integer. These solutions are therefore not applicable to my question.

Comment: Additionally, I find any response containing only search terms to defeat the purpose of the question on StackOverflow. For the record I DID search on google using any terms I could think of, including "efficient big numbers" "billion digit number arithmetic operations" "modulo operations using strings", just to name a few. The reason I made this question is BECAUSE I didn't find what I was looking for via Google.

Comment: @michaJlS if you found anything regarding those terms, if you could provide the link to that resource, because I did not.

Comment: I don't understand what "too large to represent using BigInt" means. Most biginteger implementations are limited only by available memory, or pretty close to it. Storing the digits as a "string" or "bitstring" has the same limitation. For example, in Java's `BigInteger` implementation the limit is `Integer. MAX_VALUE` *ints*, not bits, so the limit is actually `32 * Integer. MAX_VALUE` bits or about 8 GB. If you really have numbers that are larger than this but still fit in available memory than that is a more interesting problem.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah, the numbers I am talking about are that big. `java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger would overflow supported range
    at java.math.BigInteger.reportOverflow(Unknown Source)`

Comment: I have about 20 GB of RAM dedicated to the JVM I'm running this on (it's not a memory issue, as far as I'm concerned, it's a Java flavor cap, if there are ways to remove it, that works for me)

Comment: "I don't understand what 'too large to represent using BigInt' means." There's no trickery in wording or phrasing, it means EXACTLY that, `BigInteger` does not support the numbers I wish to represent and perform modulus operations on.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the Java BigInteger implementation does not allow for ints as big as I thought. I think the algorithms in the Sun/Oracle source code are pretty good for very large integers, but I see no easy way to increase the range without rewriting much of the code.